# mic and webcam permission error on epiphany

Tags: epiphany, webcam

when opening any site that require **mic** or **webcam** permission on *epiphany* theres no way i can give permission so i am unable to use any of these

unfortunately mic and webcam works fine in chrome (on elementary)
any suggestions??? or its bug...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately WebKitGTK does not support WebRTC, and will not for the foreseeable future, so there is no way to use these websites. Sorry.